# google api marker + click

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to add a custom marker to my google api: works fine except when I click on that marker, I have no event any more:

```js
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(0, 0), 5);
map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl3D());
map.addControl(new GMenuMapTypeControl());

var myIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
myIcon.image = "http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2140/1911601567_49d97f3318.jpg";
myIcon.iconSize = new GSize(80, 60);
markerOptions={};
//markerOptions = { icon:myIcon }; // if I uncomment this : no click anymore

var bounds = map.getBounds();
var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();

var point = new GLatLng(southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(),  southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random());
var marker = new GMarker(point, markerOptions);
    marker.html = 'hello world';
    map.addOverlay(marker);
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      marker.openInfoWindowHtml(marker.html);
  })
```

If I uncomment `//markerOptions = { icon:myIcon };`

I have my photo displayed, but I cannot click on marker any more.

Someone can help me? You can see it working on http://www.roulette-chat.fr/google.php.

Regards

Comment: why are you using  v2 a deprecated api. you can use v3

Answer (score 1):

I would say use api v3 instead. The one you are using is a deprecated. You can use something like below, to have your own image as a marker. To set the marker as clickable you need to use the property  `clickable:true`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
        window.onload = function(){
            // Creating a LatLng object containing the coordinate for the center of the map  
          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(56.83, 15.16);  
          // Creating an object literal containing the properties we want to pass to the map  
          var options = {  
            zoom: 7,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };  
          // Calling the constructor, thereby initializing the map  
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);  

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(56.8848, 14.7730), 
            map: map,
            title: 'My workplace',
            clickable: true,
            icon: 'url of your image'  //this is a custom marker Image
          });
        }
      })();
        </script>
```

To add an action you have to add an `eventListener` like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  //do some action
});
```